# What is the most efficient method for accessing and manipulating a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on an agent based modelling project and have a 800x800 grid that represents a landscape. Each cell in this grid is assigned certain variables. One of these variables is 'vegetation' (i.e. what functional_types this cell posses). I have a data fame that looks like follows:

[image: Vegetation variables]

Each cell is assigned a landscape_type before I access this data frame. I then loop through each cell in the 800x800 grid and assign more variables, so, for example, if cell 1 is landscape_type 4, I need to access the above data frame, generate a random number for each functional_type between the min and max_species_percent, and then assign all the variables (i.e. pollen_loading, succession_time etc etc) for that landscape_type to that cell, however, if the cumsum of the random numbers is <100 I grab function_types from the next landscape_type (so in this example, I would move down to landscape_type 3), this continues until I reach a cumsum closer to 100.

I have this process working as desired, however it is incredibly slow - as you can imagine, there are hundreds of thousands of assignments! So far I do this (self.model.veg_data is the above df):

```
    def create_vegetation(self, landscape_type):

    if landscape_type == 4:
        veg_this_patch = self.model.veg_data[self.model.veg_data['landscape_type'] <= landscape_type].copy()
    else:
        veg_this_patch = self.model.veg_data[self.model.veg_data['landscape_type'] >= landscape_type].copy()

    veg_this_patch['veg_total'] = veg_this_patch.apply(lambda x: randint(x["min_species_percent"],
                                          x["max_species_percent"]), axis=1)
    veg_this_patch['cum_sum_veg'] = veg_this_patch.veg_total.cumsum()
    veg_this_patch = veg_this_patch[veg_this_patch['cum_sum_veg'] <= 100]
    self.vegetation = veg_this_patch
```

I am certain there is a more efficient way to do this. The process will be repeated constantly, and as the model progresses, landscape_types will change, i.e. 3 become 4. So its essential this become as fast as possible! Thank you.

As per the comment: EDIT.

The loop that creates the landscape objects is given below:

```
            for agent, x, y in self.grid.coord_iter():
        # check that patch is land
        if self.landscape.elevation[x,y] != -9999.0:
            elevation_xy = int(self.landscape.elevation[x, y])

            # calculate burn probabilities based on soil and temp
            burn_s_m_p = round(2-(1/(1 + (math.exp(- (self.landscape.soil_moisture[x, y] * 3)))) * 2),4)
            burn_s_t_p = round(1/(1 + (math.exp(-(self.landscape.soil_temp[x, y] * 1))) * 3), 4)

            # calculate succession probabilities based on soil and temp
            succ_s_m_p = round(2 - (1 / (1 + (math.exp(- (self.landscape.soil_moisture[x, y] * 0.5)))) * 2), 4)
            succ_s_t_p = round(1 / (1 + (math.exp(-(self.landscape.soil_temp[x, y] * 1))) * 0.5), 4)

            vegetation_typ_xy = self.landscape.vegetation[x, y]

            time_colonised_xy = self.landscape.time_colonised[x, y]
            is_patch_colonised_xy = self.landscape.colonised[x, y]

            # populate landscape patch with values
            patch = Landscape((x, y), self, elevation_xy, burn_s_m_p, burn_s_t_p, vegetation_typ_xy,
                              False, time_colonised_xy, is_patch_colonised_xy, succ_s_m_p, succ_s_t_p)
            self.grid.place_agent(patch, (x, y))
            self.schedule.add(patch)
```

Then, in the object itself I call the create_vegetation function to add the functional_types from the above df. Everything else in this loop comes from a different dataset so isn't relevant.

Comment: Please edit your post to show how this method is being called, specifically the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract as many calculations as you can into a vectorized preprocessing step.  For example in your 800x800 loop you have:

```
burn_s_m_p = round(2-(1/(1 + (math.exp(- (self.landscape.soil_moisture[x, y] * 3)))) * 2),4)
```

Instead of executing this line 800x800 times, just do it once, during initialization:

```
burn_array = np.round(2-(1/(1 + (np.exp(- (self.landscape.soil_moisture * 3)))) * 2),4)
```

Now in your loop it is simply:

```
burn_s_m_p = burn_array[x, y]
```

Apply this technique to the rest of the similar lines.

Comment: Thank you. This will no doubt speed up those parts. However, I would really like to come up with a quicker/more efficient way of adding the subset of the df to each object. I appreciate your suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @TjBethells: Just take it one step at a time, vectorize everything that is currently obvious, then once that's done measure the time saved, make a note of it, and post a new question if it's still not fast enough.  A related low-hanging fruit is `veg_this_patch.apply(lambda ...)` - I bet you can figure out how to do that without `apply()` which will help a lot.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented your suggested changes and seen some increase in speed. Thank you. Without the call to create_vegetation my model now loads in a matter of seconds, however, including the call to create_vegetation results in a 10 - 15 minute load time! What is the best practice here? Accept this answer and create another question? Thanks.

Comment: @TjBethells: Yes, I think it'd be a good idea to take the lessons learned in this question, accept this answer, and post a new question with updated code and updated performance numbers (and also your performance goals!).  You can post a link to that question here.